# Why do I have files with garbage names in my home directory?

Tags: files

Some unknown files have appeared in my home directory on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
(base) alexander@alexander-MS-7B16:~$ ls -l
total 64
drwxrwxr-x 26 alexander alexander 4096 Oct  4 12:45  anaconda3
drwxrwxr-x  3 alexander alexander 4096 Oct 18 18:03  data
drwxr-xr-x  2 alexander alexander 4096 Dec 21 00:15  Desktop
drwxrwxr-x  2 alexander alexander 4096 Dec 22 00:44  docker
drwxr-xr-x  2 alexander alexander 4096 Nov 13 18:11  Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 alexander alexander 4096 Dec 21 00:15  Downloads
-rw-rw-r--  1 alexander alexander 1441 Oct  2 17:48  Firefox_wallpaper.png
-rw-r--r--  1 alexander alexander 4096 Dec 23 21:16 ''$'\220\021''ʎ'$'\226''U'
drwxr-xr-x  2 alexander alexander 4096 Oct  2 17:13  Music
drwxr-xr-x  2 alexander alexander 4096 Oct  2 17:13  Pictures
drwxr-xr-x  2 alexander alexander 4096 Oct  2 17:13  Public
drwxr-xr-x  4 alexander alexander 4096 Oct  2 17:33  snap
drwxr-xr-x  2 alexander alexander 4096 Oct  2 17:13  Templates
-rw-r--r--  1 alexander alexander 4096 Dec 23 22:53 ''$'\240\352\264''\'$'\373''U'
drwxr-xr-x  2 alexander alexander 4096 Oct  2 17:13  Videos
drwxrwxr-x  4 alexander alexander 4096 Dec 22 00:02  YoloV3
```

I'm talking about the files named **''$'\220\021''ʎ'$'\226''U'** and **''$'\240\352\264'''$'\373''U'**. Has anyone seen anything like this?

---

At the time when these files appeared, I was testing docker and altering my CUDA installation. I have since deleted these files with no obvious effects. I'll update here if anything changes.

Comment: What were you doing at 21:16 and 22:53 on Dec 23? Linux filenames can have any characters except NUL (0x00) and "/".